# Table where each cell equals to one object not the row

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, javafx-tableview

So usually a table row equals to one object.

Example each Person Object equals to one row in the table.

[image: example]

In my case I have a class Lesson which looks like this:

```
public class Lesson {
   private Room schoolRoom;
   private Room teachingRoom;
   private TeacherSpecialization teachingInfo;
   private WeekDay weekDay;
   private int schoolHour;  
}
```

This is what my table should look like:

[image: curricilum]

As you can see, in my case each table cell equals to one lesson object. If there is no lesson on a specific day and the specific hour the cell should be filled with a button.

How can be this done. I only now that usually each row equals to one object?

Comment: I'm not familiar with java myself, but I'd guess you'd want to create a table that represents each lesson first, then from there build the visible table instead of trying to hack at it which may cause problems in your program down the road.

Comment: I've no experience with it, but maybe ControlsFX's [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) would fit your needs?

Comment: There are certainly 3rd party controls that do calendar-alike function. If you still want to do it yourself, you need to transform your data into something like `ObservableList<LessonWeek>`. Then each day of lesson for the week would be mapped into a property in `LessonWeek`, or you could keep them the lessons in a sorted `ObservableList`.

Comment: @Jai what kind of libraries?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Jai comment. If you are pretty much looking for a simple table view for one week data, then you can align your data to suite TableView requirements and then set the items. If you requirement is more like a calendar, then the below approach may not suite.

Below is the demo if you want to convert your Lesson objects to table view data models and display. I also included to add Lessons dynamically.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LessonPlanDemo extends Application {
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    String[] rooms = {"Room1", "Room2", "Room3", "Room4", "Room5"};
    String[] trooms = {"TR1", "TR2", "TR3", "TR4", "TR5"};
    String[] subjects = {"Maths", "Science", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Drawing"};

    ObservableList<Lesson> lessons;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 640, 310);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.setTitle("Lesson Plan");
        stage.show();

        lessons = FXCollections.observableArrayList(createData());
        ObservableList<ClassHour> classHours = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        repopulate(lessons, classHours);
        lessons.addListener((ListChangeListener) e -> repopulate(lessons, classHours));

        TableView<ClassHour> tableView = new TableView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int day = i;
            TableColumn<ClassHour, Lesson> dayColumn = new TableColumn<>(WeekDay.values()[i].name());
            dayColumn.setSortable(false);
            dayColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty(param.getValue().dayLessons[day]));
            dayColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ClassHour, Lesson>, TableCell<ClassHour, Lesson>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<ClassHour, Lesson> call(TableColumn<ClassHour, Lesson> param) {
                    return new TableCell<ClassHour, Lesson>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(Lesson item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                            if (!empty) {
                                if (item != null) {
                                    setText(item.toString());
                                } else {
                                    Button btn = new Button("+ ADD");
                                    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
                                        tableView.getSelectionModel().select((ClassHour) getTableRow().getItem());
                                        showAdd(day, ((ClassHour) getTableRow().getItem()).hour, btn);
                                    });
                                    setGraphic(new StackPane(btn));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
            tableView.getColumns().addAll(dayColumn);
        }
        tableView.setItems(classHours);
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);
    }

    private void repopulate(List<Lesson> lessons, ObservableList<ClassHour> classHours) {
        classHours.clear();
        // Converting Lessons to ClassHour objects.
        lessons.forEach(lesson -> {
            ClassHour classHour = classHours.stream().filter(ch -> ch.hour == lesson.schoolHour).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (classHour == null) {
                classHour = new ClassHour(lesson.schoolHour);
                classHours.add(classHour);
            }
            classHour.dayLessons[lesson.weekDay.ordinal()] = lesson;
        });
    }

    private void showAdd(int day, int hour, Button node) {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.setAutoHide(true);

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black,yellow;-fx-background-insets:0,1;");

        ChoiceBox<String> roomBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        roomBox.getItems().addAll(rooms);
        pane.addRow(0, new Label("School room : "), roomBox);

        ChoiceBox<String> trBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        trBox.getItems().addAll(trooms);
        pane.addRow(1, new Label("Teaching room : "), trBox);

        ChoiceBox<String> subjectBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        subjectBox.getItems().addAll(subjects);
        pane.addRow(2, new Label("Subject : "), subjectBox);

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> {
            Lesson lesson = new Lesson(roomBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), trBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), subjectBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), WeekDay.values()[day], hour);
            lessons.add(lesson);
            popup.hide();
        });
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.setOnAction(e -> popup.hide());
        HBox btns = new HBox(add, cancel);
        btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        btns.setSpacing(10);

        pane.add(btns, 0, 3, 2, 1);

        popup.getContent().add(pane);
        Bounds bnds = node.localToScreen(node.getLayoutBounds());
        popup.show(node, bnds.getMinX(), bnds.getMinY() + node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private List<Lesson> createData() {
        List<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int day = 0; day < 5; day++) {
            for (int classHour = 1; classHour < 8; classHour++) {
                if (rnd.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                    lessons.add(new Lesson(rooms[rnd.nextInt(5)], trooms[rnd.nextInt(5)], subjects[rnd.nextInt(5)], WeekDay.values()[day], classHour));
                }
            }
        }
        return lessons;
    }

    class ClassHour {
        private Lesson[] dayLessons = new Lesson[7];
        private int hour;

        public ClassHour(int h) {
            this.hour = h;
        }
    }

    class Lesson {
        private Room schoolRoom;
        private Room teachingRoom;
        private TeacherSpecialization teachingInfo;
        private WeekDay weekDay;
        private int schoolHour;

        public Lesson(String sr, String tr, String subject, WeekDay wd, int hour) {
            schoolRoom = new Room(sr);
            teachingRoom = new Room(tr);
            teachingInfo = new TeacherSpecialization(subject);
            weekDay = wd;
            schoolHour = hour;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Room : " + schoolRoom.title + " - " + teachingRoom.title + "\nSubject : " + teachingInfo.subject;
        }
    }

    class Room {
        String title;

        public Room(String t) {
            this.title = t;
        }
    }

    class TeacherSpecialization {
        String subject;

        public TeacherSpecialization(String s) {
            this.subject = s;
        }
    }

    enum WeekDay {
        MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason ur example does not work for me. the empty classes (plus buttons) between for example schoolhour 10 and 15 is not shown.

Comment: @Lebron11 can you please provide the screenshot of the issue.